# Before and After innerWidth / innerHeight on Window Resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an event listener that looks like:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function(data){
    console.log(data);
    // Do something
});
```

Is there anyway to get the before resize `innerWidth` / `innerHeight` in the above callback function?  I went through the `data` object in the above code and didn't find anything there.

Comment: `before` is the key word here. See, different browsers behave differently with `resize`; even OS settings [may affect](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/resize.html) the behavior. I suppose the best bet would be to cache the previous values in your own script.

Comment: Not that I know of, but you could get the information when the page loads and store it in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up saving the old width value every time a browser resize event happened.  Code looks like:

```
var initialWidth = window.innerWidth;

window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
    // Do something with 'initialWidth'
    initialWidth = window.innerWidth;
});
```

In the above, I save the browser width on page load.  Then, every time the browser gets resized, I save the new browser width at the end of the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, you have to store previous height/width in some variables. Just put it in variables on page load and then you can access it in this method. There is nothing like bofore resize.
[read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578129/before-after-resize-event)

Answer (score 0):

Just add something to track the last `resize` event values:

```
var windowSize = (function () {
  var lastWidth = 0, lastHeight = 0;

  window.addEventListener('resize', function (data) {
    // do something with last values
    ...
    console.log(lastWidth);
    console.log(lastHeight);
    ...

    lastWidth = window.innerWidth;
    lastHeight = window.innerHeight;
  });

  return { width: lastWidth, height: lastHeight };
})();
```

Now, you can use the `windowSize` object outside the closure to find what the current window size is, and internally within the closure you can act upon the previous size of the window before updating `lastWidth` and `lastHeight`.

Hope this helps!