# Inserting div after and before on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to take each div with class of top and insert inside the div with a class of .blurb...Problem is that it adds too many repeated elements and crashes the page..Here is a code below

```
<div class="top">top1</div>
<div class="top">top2</div>
<div class="top">top3</div>

<div class="blurb">
    <p>Blurb Copy</p>
    <p>Blurb Copy</p>
    <p>Blurb Copy</p>
</div>

<div class="blurb">
    <p>Blurb Copy</p>
    <p>Blurb Copy</p>
    <p>Blurb Copy</p>
</div>

<div class="blurb">
    <p>Blurb Copy</p>
    <p>Blurb Copy</p>
    <p>Blurb Copy</p>
</div>
```

```js
function sizeUpdate() {
    var width = $(window).width(); // Get window width
    var height = $(window).height(); // Get window height

    $('.top').each(function(){
        if (width < 993) {        
            $(this).insertAfter('.blurb');
        } else if (width > 992) {
            $(this).insertBefore('.blurb');
        }
    });
};  

$(document).ready(sizeUpdate); // When the page first loads
$(window).resize(sizeUpdate); // When the browser changes size
```

Comment: how many should it add? infinite?

Comment: I would guess 3, but it would be nice if OP would give an example of expected result

Comment: Yes, my biggest confusion is if he's trying to add all three tops to each blurb or just wants one each. Kind of hard to predict since it's not exactly a real world problem.

Comment: just three, that is all that is available

Comment: Three to each blurb?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578129/before-after-resize-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are trying to achieve this:

```
    $('.top').each(function(index){
    if (width < 993) {        
        $(this).insertAfter($('.blurb')[index]);
    } else if (width > 992) {
        $(this).insertBefore($('.blurb')[index]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var canInsert = true;

 $('.top').each(function(){
        if (width < 993 && canInsert) {        
            $(this).insertAfter('.blurb');
            canInsert=false;
        } else if (width > 992 && canInsert) {
            $(this).insertBefore('.blurb');
            canInsert=false;
        }

        setTimeout(function(){
            canInsert = true;
        }, 500);
    });
```

Comment: This would theoretically prevented from inserting unless at least 500 milliseconds have gone by

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all three tops to each blurb, you could do this:

```
$('.blurb .top').remove();
$('.top').each(function() {
    var __top = $(this);
   if (width < 993) {        
        $(this).clone(true).insertAfter('.blurb');
    } else if (width > 992) {
        $(this).clone(true).insertBefore('.blurb');
    }
});
```

Basically, just clear the blurb tops before adding them. I also added the clone property, because assuming you want to add these and not just move them, you'll need duplicates of the original.