# Update Ajax Url calls when scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to update/change the AJAX call while scrolling the page. I tried this with the `scroll` handler, but it doesn't work.

```
var size = "8";
var from = "0";
var url = "mywebservice" + from + "&s=" + size;

$(document).scroll(function (e) {
  var url = "mywebservice" + from + "&s=" + size;
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {
    ++size;
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    data: { get_param: 'value' },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      $.each(data, function (index, element) {
        var HTML ='<div>' + element.name + '</div>';
        $('#container').append(HTML);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What does your html look like? as you may not be scrolling the document but an element instead

Comment: Be very, *very* wary of using this logic. The `scroll` event can potentially fire once for *every pixel* you scroll. Therefore if you scroll down the page you could potentially flood your server with 1000+ requests. I'd strongly suggest you debounce the `scroll` event if you need this behaviour

Comment: does not work means? Is the ajax is not being fired or there is any kind of error while triggering the ajax or the scroll itself is not being called. And my opinion you should place a setTimeout and cleartTimeout in scroll handler and inside that callback all stuff should reside [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392058/more-efficient-way-to-handle-window-scroll-functions-in-jquery)

Comment: Means: after the scroll handler I got a white screen, no alerts or console.log to see

Answer (score -1):

Try using alert(size) on scroll handler. If it works then your code should work too.
And i think you should assign the value of URL after the if condition. So that each time you scroll, condition will be checked and you might get incremented size if condition is true.

Comment: It's seems the scroll handler block my code, because the alert doesn't show

Comment: Yup. Thats what i thought. It means you have done some mistake in scroll event. I was just showing you the way of code. Please always cross check by writing alert on every event. I think you will get to the answer as you know where you made mistake. I cant write code for you because i dont know the exact html.

Comment: It's just a div container where i append a div inside

Comment: try only scroll event first. I mean go stepwise. First on scroll event alert some thing. then try alerting $(document).height() and every variable one by one.

Comment: So I tried, the only Issues is the scroll handler, if i set "click" all works well, i don't know why